# Storing the value of a randomly generated integer

Tags: python

I been hitting a wall that's been keeping me from tinkering on a game.

```
class Damage:
    def shortsword():
        shortsword=randint(1,6)+1
        shortsword=int(shortsword)
        return shortsword
```

I been wanting this number to pop up as part of a message on print and then use the same number as part of another function to help with subtracting of health on the target. Though each time I grab this it is always going to change.

Comment: Why `randint(1,6)+1` instead of `randint(2,7)`?! And could you review the indentation - is `shortsword` a `Damage` instance method?

Comment: You also shouldn't name variables inside the method with the same name as the method.

Comment: I am still learning the whole programming thing. I been going through Codecademy and frankly until I could put together my own program I was not able to really follow along with it. I didn't think of the part of just doing it 2,7 I was thinking that if I wanted to simulate a six sided die to do it that way and add the modifier to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems odd that you have a class with a method that doesn't use any of the class/instance attributes. Here are some other options that better use Python's functionality:

**1.** Make `shortsword` a standalone function:

```
def shortsword():
    return randint(2, 7)

damage = shortsword()
```

**2.** Make `Damage` a more useful class and `shortsword` an instance of that class:

```
class Damage:

    def __init__(self, modifier=0, die_sides=6):
        self.modifier = modifier
        self.die_sides = die_sides

    def damage(self):
        return randint(1, self.die_sides) + self.modifier

shortsword = Damage(1)

damage = shortsword.damage()
```

**3.** You could a dictionary to look up the various weapons in a `@classmethod`:

```
class Damage:

    WEAPONS = {'shortsword': (2, 7)}

    @classmethod
    def damage(cls, weapon):
        return randint(*cls.WEAPONS[weapon])

damage = Damage.damage('shortsword')
```

**4.** Finally, if you really want to use `Damage` as a class just for organisational purposes, `shortsword` should be a `@staticmethod`, as it doesn't use any class/instance attributes:

```
class Damage:

    @staticmethod
    def shortsword():
        return randint(2, 7)

damage = Damage.shortsword()
```

Comment: This is very good as well. I was using class to organize the structure for damage of the various weapons. Right now when I referenced it as a class and called it I would get a different number multiple times when trying to use it to subtract the health from the target. Thats another issue altogether. :)

Comment: @MatthewL yes, you will get a (possibly) different integer each time you call the method - you should call it once and store the value until you need a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Save the return value in a variable.

```
ret = self.shortsword() 
print ret
new_func(ret)
```

Also, you don't need to convert `shortsword` to `int`, since `randomint` returns an integer and adding `1` (an integer) to it returns an integer.

```
def shortsword():
    return randint(2, 7)
```

As mentioned by jonrsharpe in the comments, `random.randint(1, 6) + 1` gives the same result as `random.randint(2, 7)`.

Comment: If `shortsword` *is* an instance method, it should be `self.shortsword()` (inside the class) or e.g. `damage.shortsword()` (outside)

Comment: @jonrsharpe: True. I'm hoping that the OP knows how to call the function, since he states that he needs to call it twice. But, I'll fix this.

Comment: Yeah I figured out how to call them just it seemed weird that every time I try to call it I get a different number. I just wanted to do it where it would call it when the attack was put in and then when another attack comes up it would be a new number.